# how to update cordova 2.7 to 3.6.3 on mac using xcode 6.1

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova

I am getting errors while opening the old project created with cordova version 2.7 and xcode 5.1 in xcode 6.1.

i want to update the cordova lib to 3.6.3 and xcode 6.1.

Can anyone suggest the best approach to do this task.

I am using some native code and plugins also.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to create a new project using the [Cordova 3 CLI](https://github.com/apache/cordova-cli), then copy the assets across from the old project.

Trying to change your existing Cordova 2.7 project to use the 3.6.3 lib is likely to cause you more work in the long run, since there are significant differences between these versions such as the config.xml structure. Depending what version of Cordova your plugins were written for, you may need to update them to work with Cordova 3.x because the plugin interface changed ([see here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/phonegap/vLpqJER0DmQ/46EEYSJv8wEJ)).